# APIkit Router can't resolve $ref in JSON schema

Tags: mule, jsonschema

I'm using the APIkit Router and have an endpoint for posting `InvoiceGroups`. In the RAML I've specified the InvoiceGroups.schema.json (and related schemas).
Here's a simplified version of the schema:

`{
  "type" : "object",
  "id" : "urn:jsonschema:com:vatit:blaze:dto:InvoiceGroups",
  "properties" : {
    "waterline" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "description" : "Paging waterline; will be populated by the server when requesting a paged list of invoices"
    },
    "items" : {
      "type" : "array",
      "description" : "List of invoice groups",
      "items" : {
        "type" : "object",
        "id" : "urn:jsonschema:com:vatit:blaze:dto:InvoiceGroup",
        "properties" : {
          "invoices" : {
            "type" : "array",
            "items" : {
              "type" : "object",
              "id" : "urn:jsonschema:com:vatit:blaze:dto:Invoice",
              "properties" : {
                "expenseType" : {
                  "type" : "object",
                  "id" : "urn:jsonschema:com:vatit:blaze:dto:ExpenseType",
                  "description" : "Expense type info",
                  "properties" : {
                    "externalName" : {
                      "type" : "string",
                      "description" : "Descriptive name for the expense type in the external system. This is not a required field"
                    },
                    "externalId" : {
                      "type" : "string",
                      "required" : true,
                      "description" : "External expense type Id - a unique identifier to the expense type in an external system"
                    },
                    "id" : {
                      "type" : "integer",
                      "description" : "Internal Blaze Id"
                    },
                    "dragonId" : {
                      "type" : "integer",
                      "description" : "References the expense type id in Dragon - this is usually mapped by system administrators"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "items" : {
                  "type" : "array",
                  "description" : "List of invoice items - for itemised invoices.",
                  "items" : {
                    "type" : "object",
                    "id" : "urn:jsonschema:com:vatit:blaze:dto:InvoiceItem",
                    "properties" : {
                      "expenseType" : {
                        "type" : "object",
                        "$ref" : "urn:jsonschema:com:vatit:blaze:dto:ExpenseType",
                        "description" : "Expense type info"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`

When I run the app and post an object to that endpoint, I get:

`Schema validation failed: /items/1/invoices/0/items/0/expenseType: domain: $ref resolving; keyword: N/A; message: failed to get content from URI; exception-class: "org.eel.kitchen.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaException"; exception-message: "FATAL ERROR: domain: $ref resolving; keyword: N/A; message: cannot handle scheme; scheme: \"urn\"; uri: \"urn:jsonschema:com:vatit:blaze:dto:ExpenseType#\""; uri: "urn:jsonschema:com:vatit:blaze:dto:ExpenseType#"`

Is there a way for the APIkit Router to handle/resolve a json schema $ref?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no way to acomplish this at the moment. Feel free to contribute with a pull request or just raise a improvement request [here](https://github.com/mulesoft/apikit).

Comment: Thanks you. At least there's somewhere to raise improvement requests.